# Update item layout in recycler view when preference changes

Tags: android

I have simple ToDo application, each item on my recycler view has layout which contains 2 textboxes.
I have in my preferences number input that sets font size of item's textboxes on my recycler view.
When user changes font-size preference, items on my recycler view should be updated.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can take one variable of size in Adapter.
- Make setter for size variable
- Define that variable on Adapter Constructor with what ever values are there in preferences.
- OnBindView you can set that size to text view.
- On Change of Preference you can set size value by setter method of size from Adapter's object.
- Just call now notifiydataset change.

Answer (score 0):

Set the typeface on your `TextView` in the `onBindViewHolder` or `onCreateViewHolder` method based on the size you have stored in your preferences.

```
@Override
public MyFieldViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false);

    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    t.setTextSize(FONTSIZE);

    return new MyFieldViewHolder(v);
}
```